# Como accesar map vindo de um JSON sem criar structs?

Tags: golang

Após pegar alguns dados de um endpoint eu consigo passalos para uma variável do tipo `interface{}`;

```
var example interface{}
err := json.Unmarshal(payload, &example)
```

Se eu executar um `fmt.Println(example)` tenho os seguintes dados:

```
map[ticker:map[last:28533.87000000 buy:28320.00006000 sell:28533.79000000 date:1.527794277e+09 high:28599.00000000 low:27700.00001000 vol:55.58867619]]
```

Caso eu tente acessar algum valor com `example["ticker"]` tenho o seguinte erro:

> invalid operator: quotation["ticker"] (type interface{} does not support indexing)

Antes de compilar o código a análise feita é que o tipo `interface` não possui indices (o que esta correto).

Porém se eu consigo armazenar os dados em uma `interface{}` consequentemente eu poderia acessa-los correto? como posso fazer para acessar estes dados sem que ocorra esse erro na compilação?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que usar o `interface{}` não é ideal. Quando você usa o `interface` não há nenhum tipo "associado" a ele explicitamente, você precisará sempre usar o "type assertions".

---

O JSON será um `map[string]interface{}` (ou um `[]interface{}`, se for apenas uma array, sem objetos, mas não estou certo disso!).

Neste caso, para que você acesse o `example["ticker"]` o `example` precisa ser um `map[string]Tipo`, pra isso faça:

```
exampleMap := example.(map[string]interface{})
```

Agora sim, o `exampleMap` será um `map[string]` e poderá acessar `ticker`. Porém, o `ticker` também é um `interface{}` e você também terá que definir o tipo dele e assim sucessivamente.

---

Não sei se entendi o JSON corretamente, mas aparentemente isso iria obter o `last`, por exemplo:

```
var example interface{}
json.Unmarshal(payload, &example)

exampleMap := example.(map[string]interface{})
tickerMap := exampleMap["ticker"].(map[string]interface{})

fmt.Print(tickerMap["last"].(float64))
```

Você pode reduzir um pouco se especificar o `example` para `map[string]interface{}` ao invés de `interface{}`, como:

```
var example map[string]interface{}
json.Unmarshal(payload, &example)

tickerMap := example["ticker"].(map[string]interface{})

fmt.Print(tickerMap["last"].(float64))
```

Mas, ainda é mais confuso do que usar o `struct` diretamente.